# Ruby: List all items in an array

Tags: arrays, ruby, printing

I have tried at least 5 different ways to do it, currently using the .each method.

I believe the problem lies in the `print_songs` method at the bottom of the code block.

The error I'm getting:

```
Artist #print_songs lists all of the artist's songs
     Failure/Error: expect{artist.print_songs}.to output("Dirty Diana\nBillie Jean\n").to_stdout
       expected block to output "Dirty Diana\nBillie Jean\n" to stdout, but output "#<Song:0x000000019757b0>\n#<Song:0x000000019756e8>\n"
       Diff:
       @@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
       -Dirty Diana
       -Billie Jean
       +#<Song:0x000000019757b0>
       +#<Song:0x000000019756e8>
```

The code:

```
class Artist
  attr_accessor :name, :song
  @@all = []

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
    @songs = []
  end

  def add_song(song)
    @songs << song
  end

  def songs
    @songs
  end

  def self.all
    @@all
  end

  def save
    self.class.all << self
  end

  def self.create_by_name(name)
    artist = Artist.new(name)
  end

  def self.find_or_create_by_name(name)
    artist_name = @@all.detect{|x| x.name == name}
    if artist_name == nil
      self.create_by_name(name)
    else
      artist_name
    end
  end

  def print_songs
    @songs.each{|song| puts song}
  end

end
```

Song Class:

```
class Song
  attr_accessor :name, :artist

  def initialize(name)
    @name = name
  end

  # def artist=(name)
  #   self.artist = Artist.new(name)
  # end

  def self.new_by_filename(file_name)
    file_name.basename("")
  end

end
```

Answer:

```
def print_songs
  @songs.each{|song| puts song.name}
end
```

Comment: Can you post the tests you're running against this code? I tested it locally and it worked as expected - i.e `print_songs` printed all the songs added to the artist I created.

Comment: @alexnewby what is considered a `song`? simply a `String`?

Comment: It looks like in your tests that a `song` is an object of some kind, so when you print you songs you're printing the song object rather than the string of the song name.

Comment: _"I have tried at least 5 different ways to do it"_ – approaching problems this way will disguise the actual fault. If it used to work "a million times" then obviously _something else_ is wrong. You have to fix _that_ instead.

Comment: ok so the song is an object. When I do print song.to_s, it still doesn't work.

Comment: @alexnewby Did you code the song class yourself, or do you just get the instance from someplace else? In the first case, you could just define `to_s`, in the second case you'd need to look up how to get the song title (it's probably something trivial like `song.title`) and use that in your `print_songs` method.

Comment: There is another file, song.rb with a Song class. The Song belongs to Artist.

Answer (score 2):

It's apparent that the song is probably just not a string, but an object of some sort. Add a `to_s` method to whatever object that is and puts should automatically call that, although you could, of course, also call to_s manually.

Here's the quick test I did to confirm this behaviour

```
irb(main):001:0> class Song
irb(main):002:1> def initialize(title)
irb(main):003:2> @title = title
irb(main):004:2> end
irb(main):005:1> end
=> :initialize
irb(main):006:0> s = Song.new "scarborough fair"
=> #<Song:0x0000000030bb78 @title="scarborough fair">
irb(main):007:0> puts s
#<Song:0x0000000030bb78>
=> nil
irb(main):008:0> class Song
irb(main):009:1> def to_s
irb(main):010:2> return @title
irb(main):011:2> end
irb(main):012:1> end
=> :to_s
irb(main):013:0> puts s
scarborough fair
=> nil
irb(main):014:0>
```

EDIT:

#### But why is this?

In short, when you create some custom object class, like `Song` in my example above, Ruby has no idea how to represent it as a string. The default `to_s` method simply outputs the class and the object ID, which is OK for debugging, but if there's some obvious way to represent the object as a string, like in the case of `Song` (one would expect song.to_s to return the song title), one has to override the default to_s method or include / inherit from another class/module that has a more fitting implementation of `to_s`.

Comment: Why doesn't song.to_s work? Why do I need to make a new method to_s?

Comment: @alexnewby by default, the call to `to_s` prints the object's class and an encoding of the object id like this: `"#<Song:0x007f9fd16a0770>"`. In order to change this one has to override the `to_s` method

Answer (score 0):

It is working as expected.Lets look at tried.Could you post the test cases you have tried with?

```
a1 = Artist.create(name: 'Lana del re')
a1.add_song('Young and Beautiful')
a1.add_song('haunted')
a1.print_songs
["Young and Beautiful", "haunted"] #output assuming song as a String object
```

Comment: Not sure if this shouldn't be a comment rather than an answer. It doesn't really solve the problem but confirm OPs statement that it *should* work.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the call to `to_s` prints the object's class name and an encoding of the object id like so: `"#<Song:0x007f9fd16a0770>"`. That said, you need to override the `to_s` method on a `Song` class:

```
class Song
  def initialize(title)
    @title = title
  end

  def to_s
    @title
  end
end
```

Then you would need to modify the `print_songs` method accordingly on an existing `Artist` class:

```
def print_songs
  puts @songs.each(&:to_s)
end
```

The `each(&:to_s)` bit basically invokes the `to_s` method on each `Song` object passed to the block, which is essentially the same as

```
def print_songs
  puts @songs.each { |song| song.to_s }
end
```

This could've also been rewritten as just

```
def print_songs
  puts @songs
end
```

and in this case `puts` would implicitly invoke the `to_s` method on the elements of `@songs`.

Comment: That's partly incorrect; puts already takes care of calling `to_s` on non-string objects, so once you define Song.to_s, you can just do `puts instance_of_Song` and it will work just fine (see my answer, where I do precisely that in irb)

Comment: @DarkWiiPlayer good call, I should have recalled this peculiarity